# Removing parts of a string that contain digit with SED/Perl

Tags: linux, perl, bash, unix, sed

I have a data that looks like this:

```
AB208804_1 446 576 AB208804_1orf 0
AB208804_20 446 576 AB208804_20orf 0
```

I want to convert them into this:

```
AB208804 446 576 AB208804orf 0
AB208804 446 576 AB208804orf 0
```

just by removing _\digit part in column 1 and 4.

Why this line doesn't work:

```
sed 's/_\d+//g'
```

What's the correct way to do it (one-liner)?

Comment: I have no idea why this doesn't work, but if you replace `\d` with `[0-9]` it works fine.

Comment: In GNU `sed`, `\d` introduces a decimal character code of one to three digits in the range 0-255. For example, to remove a tab you could do: `sed 's/\d9//'` (or `09` or `009`) or replace some unprintable characters with spaces: `sed 's/[\d1-\d31]/ /g'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the -r switch and a character class for the sed.

```
$ echo "AB208804_1 446 576 AB208804_1orf 0" | sed -r 's/_[0-9]+//g'
AB208804 446 576 AB208804orf 0
```

Or, since you asked; in perl:

```
$ echo "AB208804_1 446 576 AB208804_1orf 0" | perl -ne 's/_\d+//g; print $_'
AB208804 446 576 AB208804orf 0
```

Comment: ITYM `perl -pe 's/_\d+//g'` :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's/_[0-9]\+//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed 's/_[0-9][0-9]*//g' file
```