# Why doesn't `\d` work in regular expressions in sed?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I am trying to use `\d` in regex in sed but it doesn't work:

```
sed -re 's/\d+//g'
```

But this is working:

```
sed -re 's/[0-9]+//g'
```

Comment: @tchrist when did i mention that i use perl

Comment: @tchrist I think you mean `perl -pe 's/\d+//g'` or rather that's what I need to use to get it to print out a file (so using it in the form: `perl -pe 's/\d+//g' example.txt > example2.txt` ) were you suggesting a different usage?

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed. It is focused on why `\d` doesn't represent a digit in sed. The question referenced as a duplicate is about "How to extract text from a string using sed."

Comment: @RobinA.Meade Agreed. Whoever voted to close the question hasn’t understood it properly.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`\d` is a switch not a regular expression macro. If you want to use some predefined "constant" instead of `[0-9]` expression just try run this code:

```
s/[[:digit:]]+//g
```

Comment: but then why `\w` works

Comment: As it's written is sed documentation

"\w
Matches any “word” character. A “word” character is any letter or digit or the underscore character."

And there's another interesting line 

"In addition, this version of sed supports several escape characters (some of which are multi-character) to insert non-printable characters in scripts (\a, \c, \d, \o, \r, \t, \v, \x). These can cause similar problems with scripts written for other seds." For more look at http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: @user2036880 as I indicate in the second part of my answer `\d` has different meaning in sed.

Comment: accepted, +30 and no one is missing \ before +

Comment: Backslash is not needed before a quantified in this regex.

Answer (score 39):

There is no such special character group in sed. You will have to use `[0-9]`.

In GNU sed, `\d` introduces a decimal character code of one to three digits in the range 0-255. 
As indicated [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421095/removing-parts-of-string-that-contain-digit-with-sed-perl-one-liner#comment3561607_3421095).

Answer (score -9):

You'd better use the Extended pattern in sed by adding `-E`.
In basic RegExp, \d and some others won't be detected

 `-E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.`

Comment: `\d` won't be detected with -E either.