# Search and replace with regex is not working in sed

Tags: regex, sed, replace, substitution

I used the following command to replace all dates with another date string in a file using sed.

```
 time sed -rn 's/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/2018-03-14/gp' date.txt
```

date.txt,

> (245176,1129,'CLEARED',to_date('1996-09-10','YYYY-MM-DD'),35097600,'Y','Y','N',to_date('1996-09-10','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Y',null,1121,null,null,null,null,1435,null,to_date('1996-09-30','YYYY-MM-DD'),null,-1,35097600,null,1117,to_date('1997-03-25','YYYY-MM-DD'),null,null,null,to_date('1997-03-25','YYYY-MM-DD'),-1,-1,to_date('1997-03-25','YYYY-MM-DD'),-1,1117,null,'ARRERGW',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,204,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

Pattern = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
Replace String = "2018-03-14"

But the above command is not working for me.. What did I wrong??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract text from a string using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/how-to-extract-text-from-a-string-using-sed) and [Why doesn't `\d` work in regular expressions in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671293/why-doesnt-d-work-in-regular-expressions-in-sed)

Comment: see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: try `ssed` it will ease your life ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify range of digits as a character class `[0-9]`:

```
sed -En 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/2018-03-14/gp' date.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ssed` (super sed) if you want to use `perl` regex:

```
$ echo '2011-03-02' | ssed -Rn 's/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/2018-03-14/gp'
2018-03-14
```

It is less portable but more powerful, so you have to chose as always between flexibility or features/performances.