# sed regexp capture groups on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed, capture-group

I'm attempting to parse a string that looks like `1.2.3` into something that looks like `1 : 2 : 3` using `sed` on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I'm currently using the command:

```
$> echo 1.2.3 | sed -r 's/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/\1 : \2 : \3/'
```

Unforunately it outputs `1.2.3` instead of `1 : 2 : 3`.

When I run the same command under Alpine 3.10 it works as expected.

Comment: sed doesn't understand `+` to mean "one or more". It also doesn't understand `\d` to mean digits. Use `[0-9][0-9]*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't \`\d\` work in regular expressions in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671293/why-doesnt-d-work-in-regular-expressions-in-sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
echo '1.2.3' | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/\1 : \2 : \3/'
```

```
1 : 2 : 3
```

`\d` is a perl property for `[[:digit:]]` and is not available in most of the `sed`

You can also use:

```
sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+)\.([[:digit:]]+)\.([[:digit:]]+)/\1 : \2 : \3/' <<< "1.2.3"
```