# Printing only text from group

Tags: regex, sed

I have working example of substitution in online regex tester https://regex101.com/r/3FKdLL/1 and I want to use it as a substitution in sed editor.

```
echo "repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" | sed -r 's/^([\w-]+)-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.gz$.*/\1/p'
```

It always prints whole string: `repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz`, but not matched group `[\w-]+`.
I expect to get only text from group which is `repo` string in this example.

Comment: @NickReed Sed doesn't support `\K` (PCRE).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sure enough, I tried it with `-r` and it doesn't work. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" |
sed -rn 's/^([A-Za-z]+)-[[:alnum:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}.gz.*$/\1/p'
```

Explanations:

- `\w` will work (not `[\w]` wich matches [either backslash or w](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202231/138686)), but you should use `[[:alnum:]]` which is POSIX
- For `sed`, `\d` [isn't a regex class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14671415/4375327), but an [escaped character representing a non-printable character](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)
- Add `-n` to mute sed, with `/p` to explicitly print matched lines

---

Additionaly, you could refactor your regex by removing duplication:

```
echo "repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" |
sed -rn 's/^([[:alnum:]]+)-[[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){5}.gz.*$/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for GNU grep :

```
echo "repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" | grep -oP '^\K[[:alpha:]-]+'
```

Displays :

```
repo-
```

On this example :

```
echo "repo-repo-2019-12-31-14-30-11.gz" | grep -oP '^\K[[:alpha:]-]+'
```

Displays :

```
repo-repo-
```

Which I think is what you want because you tried with `[\w-]+` on your regex.

If I'm wrong, just replace the grep command with : `grep -oP '^\K\w+'`

Comment: nice to know, but how remove last dash?